Pass information into Provider from Module OPTIONALLY
I have provider:
export const SomeProvider = {
  provide: "Name",
  inject: [ 
    UserRepository,
    AnotherRepository,

    "ProvidersName",
  ],
  useFactory: async (
    user: UserRepository,
    another: AnotherRepository,  
    options: { throwError?: boolean },
  ) => {

    if (!!user.some((x) => !!x.details["user_account_id"])) {
      return user;
    }

        if (!!another.some((x) => !!x.details["another_account_id"])) {
      return another;
    }

    if (options?.throwError)
      throw new Error("No connection found for someone");
  },
};

And 2 modules:
@Module({
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [
    SomeProvider
    {
      provide: "ProvidersName",
      useValue: { throwError: false },
    },
  ],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity]),
  ],
})
export class UserModule {}


@Module({
  controllers: [AnotherController],
  providers: [
    SomeProvider
    {
      provide: "ProvidersName",
      useValue: { throwError: true },
    },
  ],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AnotherEntity]),
  ],
})
export class AnotherModule {}

I want that 'throwError' was in provider as true by default and I shoudn't register them in different depended modules. From UserModule I want to rewrite it by setting false. But by default it is true
I tried to register provider in each module but it is not what I want. I want to have a default state of flag to avoid passing the options from all modules but UserModule

Step 1: Create a Global Configuration Module
// config.module.ts
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';

@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'ProvidersName',
      useValue: { throwError: true }, // Default value
    },
  ],
  exports: ['ProvidersName'],
})
export class ConfigModule {}

Step 2: Update SomeProvider to Use the Configuration
// some.provider.ts
export const SomeProvider = {
  provide: 'Name',
  inject: [UserRepository, AnotherRepository, 'ProvidersName'],
  useFactory: async (
    user: UserRepository,
    another: AnotherRepository,
    options: { throwError?: boolean },
  ) => {
    if (user.some((x) => !!x.details['user_account_id'])) {
      return user;
    }

    if (another.some((x) => !!x.details['another_account_id'])) {
      return another;
    }

    if (options?.throwError) {
      throw new Error('No connection found for someone');
    }

    return null; // Or any default value if needed
  },
};

Step 3: Use the Global Configuration in Modules
// user.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { SomeProvider } from './some.provider';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { UserEntity } from './user.entity';

@Module({
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [
    SomeProvider,
    {
      provide: 'ProvidersName',
      useValue: { throwError: false }, // Override the default value
    },
  ],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity]),
  ],
})
export class UserModule {}

In Other Modules, No Need to Register the Configuration
// another.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { SomeProvider } from './some.provider';
import { AnotherController } from './another.controller';
import { AnotherEntity } from './another.entity';

@Module({
  controllers: [AnotherController],
  providers: [SomeProvider],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AnotherEntity]),
  ],
})
export class AnotherModule {}

Step 4: Import the Global Module in the Root Module
// app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from './config.module';
import { UserModule } from './user.module';
import { AnotherModule } from './another.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule, // Import the global configuration module
    UserModule,
    AnotherModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

